# Signing an Assembly with Nant

Tags: .net, nant, signing, strongname

How do I automatically add a strong name to a `.NET` assembly using a `nant` task?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [delay-sign task](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.85/help/tasks/delay-sign.html):

Sign partially-signed `foo.dll` with `bar.snk`:

```
<delay-sign keyfile="bar.snk" verbose="false">
    <targets>
        <include name="foo.dll" />
    </targets>
</delay-sign>
```

This might also be of interest: [NAnt task for Code Signing](http://www.isi-net.com/Blogs/Ron-Muth/NAnt-task-for-Code-Signing)